# ArcGIS JavaScript API: SEC7127: Redirect was blocked for CORS request after submitting geoprocessing job

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, cors

Using the ArcGIS for JavaScript API 3.19, I'm submitting a job to the ExtractData geoprocessing service at:

https://analysis7.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/tasks/GPServer/ExtractData/submitJob

The job is submitted and run successfully, and the output is created in my ArcGIS Online root folder.

**However**, I can't figure out how to get the response back from the server. When I submit the job, the JavaScript console reports 2 errors:

> SEC7127: Redirect was blocked for CORS request.
>
> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x800c0014, A redirection problem occurred.

This sort of makes sense to me, because the server issues a redirect to the job page. I can see that the server responds with a status of 303, and includes the URL to the job in the response. However, the code that I have to handle the response (see below) is never called.

```
var url = _extractDataURL +
    "?inputLayers=" + inputLayers +
    "&extent=" + extent +
    "&clip=" + clip +
     "&dataFormat=" + dataFormat +
     "&outputName=" + outputName +
     "&context=" + context +
     "&f=" + f +
     "&token=" + IdentityManager.credentials[0].token;

var xmlHTTPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHTTPRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlHTTPRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlHTTPRequest.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
}

xmlHTTPRequest.onload = function () {
    console.log(this.responseText);
}

xmlHTTPRequest.open("GET", url, true);
xmlHTTPRequest.send();
```

How can I configure things so that the redirect (the correct response) doesn't cause the CORS error, and so that I can handle the response and get the URL to the job?

Comment: have you tried using "jsonp" as your dataType in the javascript ajax call?

Comment: You said you're using the ArcGIS JS API 3.19 - can you use [esri/tasks/Geoprocessor](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/geoprocessor-amd.html#submitjob) instead of rolling your own XMLHttpRequest? Not sure if it'll solve your problem but may make your code a bit simpler.

Comment: @Brad _jsonp_ isn't a supported data type for this operation, but I tried with _f=json_, and that worked: no errors and the response returned correctly. Interesting ... so why does CORS allow a JSON response but not an HTML response?

Comment: I should have paid closer attention.  jsonp is not needed since you are using CORS... json is just text so it wouldn't try to redirect.

Comment: @GavinR I can run the job using esri/tasks/Geoprocessor: the result is created successfully. However, i end up with a different problem. The status callback returns an error: 

"Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference"

despite the fact that I've provided all of the parameters defined at:

https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/analysis/api-reference/extract-data.htm

and the job executing successfully.

Comment: @SpatialBridge can you please post your updated code that is causing that error?